# How to get Javascript to stop removing my padding from expand / collapse bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It seems my JS is removing my padding styles on css selector **.header span**

I'm not super sure why, or how to get it to stop so any answers would be greatly appericated.

Below is my current markup.

```js
$(".header").click(function() {
  $header = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $header.next();
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(220, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $header.text(function() {
      //change text based on condition
      return $content.is(":visible") ? "Show less" : "Show more";
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

.ob_hero {
  background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.ob__herowrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.ob__herowrapper picture img {
  max-width: 80vw;
}

.btn_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.herobtn_container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.herobtn_wrapper {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  flex-basis: 45%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.herobtn_1 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.expand {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.expand div {
  width: 100%;
}

.expand .header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header span {
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
}

.expand .content {
  display: none;
}


/* Make Hero Buttons 100% on Mobile
    
    @media (max-width:50em) {
        .herobtn_container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    
    */


/* Tablet */

@media (min-width:30em) and (max-width:50em) {
  .ob_hero {
    background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
  }
  .herobtn_wrapper {
    flex-basis: 45%;
  }
  .ob__herowrapper picture img {
    max-width: 70vw;
  }
}


/* Mobile */

@media (max-width:30em) {
  .ob_hero {
    background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
  }
  .herobtn_wrapper {
    flex-basis: 45%;
  }
  .ob__herowrapper picture img {
    max-width: 70vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ob_hero">
  <div class="ob__herowrapper">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 50em)" srcset="http://svgshare.com/i/4H9.svg" width="100%" />
      <source media="(min-width: 0em)" srcset="http://svgshare.com/i/4J0.svg" width="100%" /> <img alt="ALT HERE" src="http://svgshare.com/i/4H9.svg" width="100%" /> </picture>
    <div class="btn_wrapper">
      <div class="herobtn_container">
        <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
          <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP WOMEN</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
          <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP MEN</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
          <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP GIRLS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
          <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP BOYS</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="expand">
    <div class="header"><span>Show more</span> </div>
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li>Valid In-Store & Online, Today Only</li>
        <li>Online Code: <strong>CLEARANCE15</strong></li>
        <li>Exclusions apply.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I thought about using CSS transitions, but I'm sure there is some javascript guru who has a simple fix for this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a span that is being removed when you click on *"show less/show more"* because you are changing the content of the header as a text. So you may change `text()` to `html()` and instead of simple text add the span with content :

```js
$(".header").click(function () {
        $header = $(this);
        //getting the next element
        $content = $header.next();
        //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
        $content.slideToggle(220, function () {
            //execute this after slideToggle is done
            //change text of header based on visibility of content div
            $header.html(function () {
                //change text based on condition
                return $content.is(":visible") ? "<span>Show less</span>" : "<span>Show more</span>";
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0px 0px;
    }
    
    .ob_hero {
        background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .ob__herowrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 48%;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        /* Safari */
        transform: translate(0, -50%);
    }
    
    .ob__herowrapper picture img {
        max-width: 80vw;
    }
    
    .btn_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -50px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        /* Safari */
        transform: translate(0, -50%);
    }
    
    .herobtn_container {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .herobtn_wrapper {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        flex-basis: 45%;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    .herobtn_1 {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .expand {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: #eee;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
    
    .expand div {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .expand .header {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .header span {
        padding: 1em;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .expand .content {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Make Hero Buttons 100% on Mobile
    
    @media (max-width:50em) {
        .herobtn_container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    
    */
    /* Tablet */
    
    @media (min-width:30em) and (max-width:50em) {
        .ob_hero {
            background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
        }
        .herobtn_wrapper {
            flex-basis: 45%;
        }
        .ob__herowrapper picture img {
            max-width: 70vw;
        }
    }
    /* Mobile */
    
    @media (max-width:30em) {
        .ob_hero {
            background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
        }
        .herobtn_wrapper {
            flex-basis: 45%;
        }
        .ob__herowrapper picture img {
            max-width: 70vw;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ob_hero">
    <div class="ob__herowrapper">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width: 50em)" srcset="http://svgshare.com/i/4H9.svg" width="100%" />
            <source media="(min-width: 0em)" srcset="http://svgshare.com/i/4J0.svg" width="100%" /> <img alt="ALT HERE" src="http://svgshare.com/i/4H9.svg" width="100%" /> </picture>
        <div class="btn_wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn_container">
                <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
                    <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP WOMEN</div>
                </div>
                <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
                    <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP MEN</div>
                </div>
                <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
                    <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP GIRLS</div>
                </div>
                <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
                    <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP BOYS</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="expand">
        <div class="header"><span>Show more</span> </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>Valid In-Store & Online, Today Only</li>
                <li>Online Code: <strong>CLEARANCE15</strong></li>
                <li>Exclusions apply.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can also edit your HTML/CSS and keep the JS as it is :

```js
$(".header").click(function () {
        $header = $(this);
        //getting the next element
        $content = $header.next();
        //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
        $content.slideToggle(220, function () {
            //execute this after slideToggle is done
            //change text of header based on visibility of content div
            $header.text(function () {
                //change text based on condition
                return $content.is(":visible") ? "Show less" : "Show more";
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0px 0px;
    }
    
    .ob_hero {
        background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .ob__herowrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 48%;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        /* Safari */
        transform: translate(0, -50%);
    }
    
    .ob__herowrapper picture img {
        max-width: 80vw;
    }
    
    .btn_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -50px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        /* Safari */
        transform: translate(0, -50%);
    }
    
    .herobtn_container {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .herobtn_wrapper {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        flex-basis: 45%;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    .herobtn_1 {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .expand {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: #eee;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
    
    .expand div {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .expand .header {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 1em;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    

    
    .expand .content {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Make Hero Buttons 100% on Mobile
    
    @media (max-width:50em) {
        .herobtn_container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    
    */
    /* Tablet */
    
    @media (min-width:30em) and (max-width:50em) {
        .ob_hero {
            background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
        }
        .herobtn_wrapper {
            flex-basis: 45%;
        }
        .ob__herowrapper picture img {
            max-width: 70vw;
        }
    }
    /* Mobile */
    
    @media (max-width:30em) {
        .ob_hero {
            background-image: url(https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/20171102_hpc_clearance_lg?scl=1&qlt=60);
        }
        .herobtn_wrapper {
            flex-basis: 45%;
        }
        .ob__herowrapper picture img {
            max-width: 70vw;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ob_hero">
    <div class="ob__herowrapper">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width: 50em)" srcset="http://svgshare.com/i/4H9.svg" width="100%" />
            <source media="(min-width: 0em)" srcset="http://svgshare.com/i/4J0.svg" width="100%" /> <img alt="ALT HERE" src="http://svgshare.com/i/4H9.svg" width="100%" /> </picture>
        <div class="btn_wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn_container">
                <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
                    <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP WOMEN</div>
                </div>
                <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
                    <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP MEN</div>
                </div>
                <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
                    <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP GIRLS</div>
                </div>
                <div class="herobtn_wrapper">
                    <div class="herobtn_1">SHOP BOYS</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="expand">
        <div class="header">Show more</div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>Valid In-Store & Online, Today Only</li>
                <li>Online Code: <strong>CLEARANCE15</strong></li>
                <li>Exclusions apply.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @adambwhitten also added another solution by changing only HTML/CSS

Comment: is there an easy way to have an icon change in addition to the text? like if i used css to flip an icon up and down?

Comment: @adambwhitten yes sure, since i changed text to html you are able to inser html .. so you can do for example `<span><i class='icon' ></i>Show 
 more</span>` and the same for show less. You can also use image, or even change it with CSS

Comment: So would that be for example 1 or 2?

Comment: @adambwhitten it would be for the example 1 ;) as in the 2 i kept your original JS .. so for example 2 we can proceed with another method

Comment: nah, example 1 works perfect. just making sure. unless you know of a better way to do it all together? something more pretty? otherwise you nailed it dude.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160961/discussion-between-adambwhitten-and-temani-afif).

Comment: @adambwhitten there is no *better* way :) just use the one you are confortable with and you understand well ... then there is a lot of method to do it ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is not removing the padding, it is removing the entire `<span>` element. `$header` is the `<div class="header">` and you are overriding it's content. Use `.find('span')` to access the child node:

```
$header.find('span').text(function () {
    //change text based on condition
    return $content.is(":visible") ? "Show less" : "Show more";
});
```